# how do I append a dictionary to list that is contained inside another list which is inside a dictionary?

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, nested-lists

Required Output:

```
{'students': [courses[{'id2': 2}, {'id3':3}]]}
```

Implementation

```
data={"students": []}
data["students"].append({'courses': []})
i = 2
```

Data contains a dictionary, students contains a list, and courses contains a list. I want to append data inside courses.

```
data["students"]['courses'].append({'id2': i})
print(data)
```

When I use the above code I get the following error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

```
data["students"][0].append({'id2': i})
```

When I use the above code I get the error: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'

```
data["students"][0]=({'id2': i})
```

When I use the above code, it will replace courses list.
Output:

```
{'students': [{'id2': 2}]}
```

It would be of great help if anyone can help me out. Thanks a ton in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer:

```
data["students"][0]['courses'].append({'id2': i})
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.